# Maxscript as Modifier or Geometry object

Tags: 3dsmax, modifier, maxscript

My script is a detached rollout with a multiple options where under a UI I just create Cyllinder and assign some modifiers as Bend, Noise and etc. But my general problem, if I close my script rollout I can't be able modify object after that and my object displays just as a stack of modifiers. How to collect my script into a one modifier or geometry object with possible to modify any parameters in any time?

Update: Applying modifiers to mesh:

```
myMesh = cylinder smooth:on heightsegs:(heightSpin2.value / 10) capsegs:1 
sides:12 height:heightSpin2.value radius:radSpin2.value mapcoords:on 
realWorldMapSize:on isSelected:on

modPanel.addModToSelection (Noisemodifier ()) ui:on
myMesh .modifiers[#Noise].scale = scaleSpin2.value 
myMesh .modifiers[#Noise].strength  = [distSpin2.value,distSpin2.value ,distSpin2.value ]
myMesh .modifiers[#Noise].frequency = 2.14 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Scripted SimpleObject Plug-ins](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-C0BFFE27-BB59-4265-8F70-BFE8A636F7CB.htm,topicNumber=d30e642485) (for custom primitives) and [Scripted SimpleMeshMod Plug-ins](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_7AAEEA29_A627_43CF_B2F8_8B8BBB20F5E4_htm) (for custom modifiers). Both these concepts are also exposed to the Max Creation Graph (MCG).

Comment: Swordslayer Thank you for advice! Scripred SimpleObj Plugin looks fine for my purpose, I repeated the code as in first link, but when I start it brings up my custom menu, when I push my create button on rollout, it sends me to stack of modifiers. And from now my menu not be available. How to stay this transformations under the cover of my plugin? I apply modifiers as code above (look update). It's correct way applying modifiers "under the cover"?

Comment: Looks like you don't quite understand, in SimpleObject, you do everything yourself, no modifiers, no ready-made modules. Check [scripted star primitive](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/star) for an example. If you don't feel comfortable scripting (the code you show looks like a slightly edited macrorecorder output, not something a scripter would write), definitely check MCG instead, it's more modular and abstracts the mesh manipulation part pretty well.

Comment: Swordslayer Thank you, I got it. Hard to hear that, because all of my transformation linked to max's modifiers. My goal was to combine all modifiers parameters in the one UI, but with possibility rebuild mesh in any time. I don't have MCG (3dsmax 2014) unfortunately. :((

Comment: Well, you can add multiple modifiers and expose their properties in one UI with custom attributes. That's what I do with the [InsetChamferStack](http://www.scriptspot.com/files/insetfixchamferstack_0.ms). With a small number of modifiers that might make sense, but it's definitely not a universal solution.